# storeEval number is ok, but text - fails

Tags: selenium

I use [soda selenium](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) for integration tests.
The following code works:

I save height of element and use it next in the test:

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
        browser.storeEval("window.jQuery('.logo').height();", "height", function(err, body, res){
            browser.getEval('${height}',function(err,val){
                if(err !== null) throw err
                console.log(val) //------ it outputs 66 in console, so it works well
                browser.testComplete(function(){ });
            });
        });
    });
})
```

When I try to get text of element `window.jQuery('h2.logo').text();` it fails:

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
        browser.storeEval("window.jQuery('h2.logo').text();", "text", function(err, body, res){
            browser.getEval('${text}',function(err,val){
                if(err !== null) throw err
                console.log(val) // ------------------------- null
                browser.testComplete(function(){ });
            });
        });
    });
})
```

It prints `null` in console. So h2 text is null but when I check it on browser console it prints:

```
window.jQuery('h2.logo').text()
"jQuery"
```

So how to store h2 text and use it further in test?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using the [`storeText()`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeText) instead of `storeEval()`? Anyway, this should work. Could you try `var text = browser.getText(...);` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx, Slanec. getText works good for me:

```
var soda = require('soda')
    , assert = require('assert');
var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
    , port: 4444
    , url: 'http://jquery.com'
    , browser: 'firefox'
});
browser.session(function(err){
    browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
        browser.getText('css=h2.logo',function(err,val){
            if(err !== null) throw err
            console.log(val) //------------------- jQuery
            browser.testComplete(function(){ });
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: I'm glad you made it. Not sure why your previous solution didn't work, though. I feel obliged to tell you that Selenium RC has been oficially deprecated two years ago and the currently recommended Selenium technology is [Selenium WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/). [There are JavaScript bindings for WebDriver, too.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) So if you have been using Soda for years, no problem, use it on. If you have just begun and want to use something actually supported, newer and better, try WebDriver.